# access two tags in for loop xml etree python

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I have an xml file containing information on several dates and events/categories for those dates. Ideally, I want to pick all events with dates after March 10, 2015 and other tags for events with the same date. The file looks something like this,

```
<information>
   <description>
         <date> 03032015 </date>
         <category> JJ </category>
         <category> JJ </category>
         <type> BB </type>
    </description>
    <description>
         <date> 10032015 </date>
         <category> JJ </category>
         <type> BB </type>
    </description>
</information>
```

This is what I have tried so far...

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

doc = ET.ElementTree(filename)
for i in xrange(500):
    obj = root.getchildren()[i].getchildren()
    row = dict(zip(['Date', 'Category', 'Type'], [obj[0].text, obj[1].text, obj[2].text]))
    row_dF = pd.Series(row)
    row_dF.name = i
    dF = dF.append(row_dF)
```

The main issue is that for some events there's more than one item for the same tag (as in with category).  I tried it a different way, but I am still not quite doing the loops properly.  Any suggestions?

```
date= [k for k in data.iter(tag='date')]
cat = [j.text for j in data.iter(tag='category')]
typ = [i.text for i in data.iter(tag='type')]
```

Comment: can you post the expected output (dictionary) given that XML as input?

Comment: What you have "tried so far" cannot be the real code. It does not run. Please provide complete code that executes. Explain what output you want.